# MS Word - Creating Template Text

Tags: ms-word

I need to create lines of text that say something like `[Insert text here]`, but when you click *anywhere* between those brackets, the **entire bracket (text included)** gets highlighted.  If you use some of Words' templates, these kind of sentences appear as placeholders.  This is what I am trying to accomplish; placeholder text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>... type the text `[macrobutton nomacro "your text here"]` inside the brackets.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> will toggle the code on and off.